# In the react big calender, in week view, i want to display week days with dates, in place of time slots with hourly gap, and on top only resources

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the react-big-calender, in the week view, it is showing on top bar with resources and under it, week days, and on left side hourly time slots with 1 hour gap.  I want to have a functionality such that, when i click week view, on top bar only resources should display, and left side, instead of time slots, only week dates with days.

I want to have a functionality such that, when i click week view, on top bar only resources should display, and left side, instead of time slots, only week dates with days.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.